# An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file " " failed

Tags: c#, sql-server, localdb

When I am running the application on my computer it works fine. Even when I publish it to be a one-click application everything seems to work great. However, when I transfer the application to another computer it seems to carry on the old data from the computer it was published on. Then it gives me this error:

> An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file " "A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share."

I didn't add the file name because I do not have the other computer with me.

I try looking it up online and I haven't had any luck finding the answer to my problem. I even installed a local db on the other computer but it still does not work.

this is my connection string.

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source = (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB; AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\benja\Desktop\Database Project\Bonne Naissance 2.0\Bonne Naissance 2.0\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security;");
```

this the app config connection string.

```
 <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Bonne_Naissance_2._0.Properties.Settings.Database1ConnectionString"
        connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: DO NOT put the AttachDbFilename property into the connection string.  It is not needed if the database is already attached to the database.  Use Initial Catalog which will select the default database on the server you are using.

Comment: @jdweng when I replace the AttachDbFilename to Initial Catalog this is the error it gives me - 'Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 148.'

Comment: See connectionstrings.com for format of the parameters : https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

Comment: @jdweng i looked over it but it mainly using sqlexpress there aren't that many info on the local db. So I am wondering if you know any other way I can bypass this error. Should I detach the database?

Comment: LocalDB is just the IP address (or name of computer) where database is located.  Has nothing to do with issue.  The connections string for Express and Standard are the same.  Express does not have full functionality (nothing to do with the connection string).

Comment: @jdweng I am sorry but I tried it but it didn't work now I don't know what to do. It only been a few months since I have been using database. So I'm sorry if I seem slow I'm still new at this.

Comment: First use SQL Server Management Studio on deploy computer and try to connect to the SQL Server you want to use.  It should say on login GUI : Window Credential (which is Integrated Security True).  The use Explorer in SSMS and open up the Databases to check name of database so you can enter initial database in connection string : SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source = (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB; Initial Catalog="name of database";Integrated Security;");  The instance of database may be different and check login window for instance name.

Comment: @jdweng it still does not work

Comment: You are not telling anything to help.  "Does not work" can mean a lot of different things.

Comment: @jdweng I did what you told me to do and I even tried changing the connection string but it still carrying the data from the deployed computer and it still giving me the same error.

Comment: The only association between the deploy computer and the database is the "Data Source" and the AttachDbFilename.  Once you remove the AttachDbFilename then you only have to make sure the "Data Source" is correct.  I would use SQL Server Management Studio to query the database to make sure the deployed computer has the correct data.

Comment: @jdweng ohh okay can you show me how the data source would look like without the AttachDbFilename because I feel like I am missing something. Thank you so much for helping me.

Comment: SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source = (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB; Integrated Security;");.  You can see all the option here : https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/